# Sitecore XP 9.1 Installation Error - The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists

Tags: sql-server, solr, sitecore, sitecore9

Super new to Sitecore in general but I've been following this [guide](https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/11/29/sitecore-xp-9-1-step-by-step-install-guide-on-your-machine/) to setup Sitecore 9.1. I'm running a laptop on Windows 10, SQL Express 2017 with SQL Server Management Studio and SIF version 2.0. However, I'm running into an issue when I get to step 10 where I run **execute .\sc91_install**. I get this error:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\sc91_install\sc91_install.ps1:76 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:09
Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.3.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask
```

Here's how my sc91_install file looks

```
$InstallDirectory = "C:\websites\"
# The Prefix that will be used on SOLR, Website and Database instances.
$Prefix = "sc910"
# The Password for the Sitecore Admin User. This will be regenerated if left on the default.
$SitecoreAdminPassword = "SIF-Default"
# The root folder with the license file and WDP files.
$SCInstallRoot = "C:\sc91_install"
# The name for the XConnect service.
$XConnectSiteName = "$prefix.xconnect.local"
# The Sitecore site instance name.
$SitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.local"
# Identity Server site name
$IdentityServerSiteName = "$prefix.identityserver.local"
# The Path to the license file
$LicenseFile = "$SCInstallRoot\license.xml"
# The URL of the Solr Server
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8984/solr"
# The Folder that Solr has been installed to.
$SolrRoot = "C:\Solr\solr-7.2.1"
# The Name of the Solr Service.
$SolrService = "Solr-7.2.1"
# The DNS name or IP of the SQL Instance.
$SqlServer = "WKWZTMHKO2GYV0Y\SQLEXPRESS"
# A SQL user with sysadmin privileges.
$SqlAdminUser = "sa"
# The password for $SQLAdminUser.
$SqlAdminPassword = "Adminpw1!"
# The path to the XConnect Package to Deploy.
$XConnectPackage = (Get-ChildItem "$SCInstallRoot\Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. * (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip").FullName
# The path to the Sitecore Package to Deploy.
$SitecorePackage = (Get-ChildItem "$SCInstallRoot\Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. * (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip").FullName
# The path to the Identity Server Package to Deploy.
$IdentityServerPackage = (Get-ChildItem "$SCInstallRoot\Sitecore.IdentityServer 2.0.0 rev. * (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip").FullName
# The Identity Server password recovery URL, this should be the URL of the CM Instance
$PasswordRecoveryUrl = "http://$SitecoreSiteName"
# The URL of the Identity Server
$SitecoreIdentityAuthority = "https://$IdentityServerSiteName"
# The URL of the XconnectService
$XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectSiteName"
# The random string key used for establishing connection with IdentityService. This will be regenerated if left on the default.
$ClientSecret = "SIF-Default"
# Pipe-separated list of instances (URIs) that are allowed to login via Sitecore Identity.
$AllowedCorsOrigins = "http://$SitecoreSiteName"


# Install XP0 via combined partials file.
$singleDeveloperParams = @{
    Path = "$SCInstallRoot\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json"
    InstallDirectory = $InstallDirectory
    SqlServer = $SqlServer
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
    SitecoreAdminPassword = $SitecoreAdminPassword
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
    SolrService = $SolrService
    Prefix = $Prefix
    XConnectCertificateName = $XConnectSiteName
    IdentityServerCertificateName = $IdentityServerSiteName
    IdentityServerSiteName = $IdentityServerSiteName
    LicenseFile = $LicenseFile
    XConnectPackage = $XConnectPackage
    SitecorePackage = $SitecorePackage
    IdentityServerPackage = $IdentityServerPackage
    XConnectSiteName = $XConnectSiteName
    SitecoreSitename = $SitecoreSiteName
    PasswordRecoveryUrl = $PasswordRecoveryUrl
    SitecoreIdentityAuthority = $SitecoreIdentityAuthority
    XConnectCollectionService = $XConnectCollectionService
    ClientSecret = $ClientSecret
    AllowedCorsOrigins = $AllowedCorsOrigins
}

Push-Location $SCInstallRoot

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper.log

# Uncomment the below line and comment out the above if you want to remove the XP0 SingleDeveloper Config
#Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XP0-SingleDeveloper-Uninstall.log

Pop-Location
```

I've tried restarting my IIS but that didn't seem to work. Please let me know if additional info is needed. Would be super grateful if anyone could provide some assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your installation settings seem to be Ok.

Likely you have either the Sitecore's application pools/sites stopped in IIS or ports 80 / 443 used by other sites without dedicated hostnames.

Open your IIS and make sure that all Sitecore related application pools & sites are started and configured to use the desired ports. Especially, ensure that the Sitecore Identity Server site is up & running as if it is unavailable then the SIF script can't start your Sitecore instance and, therefore, complete the installation process.